# Why is my conditional echo-ing the wrong thing

Tags: php, css, conditional-statements

I have something like

*just a snipplet*

```
$i = 1; while (...) {
    echo ($i % 5 == 1) ? 'class="first-col"' : ($i % 5 == 0) ? 'class="last-col"' : '';
    $i++;
}
```

but even when `$i % 5 == 1`, I will get `class="last-col"` echo-ed is my logic right?

This is actually a CSS fix for IE so that I wont need to use `nth-child`. I am trying to target the 1st and last columns of my grid which contains 5 col/row

Comment: Because ternary operator is as ugly as hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?:` operator is left-associative, i.e. you have

```
echo ( ($i % 5 == 1) ? 'class="first-col"' : ($i % 5 == 0) ) ? 'class="last-col"' : '';
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

It is best not to nest ternary operators.
Better use `if` / `elseif` / `else` constructs, they are more legible.

Comment: This looks good to me personally: `if($i % 5 == 1){ echo 'class="first-col"'; } elseif ($i % 5 == 0){ echo 'class="last-col"'; }`

Answer (score 2):

adding parenthesis helps:

`echo (($i % 5 == 1) ? 'class="first-col"' : (($i % 5 == 0) ? 'class="last-col"' : ''));`

Answer (score 1):

For a start you're using nested ternary operations. I'd at least use brackets around the individual conditions to make it obvious what should be carried out first.